# Access VBA If statement to Change Back and Font color of a report field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to make a field on a report highlight in red with white bold font on a report when it has an "S" populated.  This keeps making all records in the field red.  Please help!

```
Private Sub Report_Activate()
If Me![PULL STATUS] = "S" Then

Me![PULL STATUS].BackColor = vbRed
Me![PULL STATUS].FontBold = True
Me![PULL STATUS].ForeColor = vbWhite

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have should be contained in the  ***On Format*** event of the ***Detail*** section of the report.  When you set the `BackColor`, `FontBold`, and `ForeColor`it stays that way until it is changed again.

So what you need is an else statement to perform the opposite if not true.  Something like:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
  If Me![PULL STATUS] = "S" Then
    Me![PULL STATUS].BackColor = vbRed
    Me![PULL STATUS].FontBold = True
    Me![PULL STATUS].ForeColor = vbWhite
  Else
    Me![PULL STATUS].BackColor = vbWhite
    Me![PULL STATUS].FontBold = False
    Me![PULL STATUS].ForeColor = vbBlack
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working.  Is this supposed to take effect when the report opens?

Comment: Yes, it takes affect while it is formatting each record in the detail section.  Did you add the code in the On Format Event of the Details section?

Comment: 'Private Sub Detail_FORMAT(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

  If Me![PULL STATUS] = "S" Then
    Me![PULL STATUS].BackColor = vbRed
    Me![PULL STATUS].FontBold = True
    Me![PULL STATUS].ForeColor = vbWhite
  Else
    Me![PULL STATUS].BackColor = vbWhite
    Me![PULL STATUS].FontBold = False
    Me![PULL STATUS].ForeColor = vbBlack
  End If
End Sub
'

Comment: If you are not seeing any effect at all and no error either, then the code is not running.  The code may not be linked to the event.  Did you paste the code directly into the VBA editor, or did you go through the details section and the On format event and then paste the code?

Comment: I went into the VBA editor, to the report, then set it to detail and onformat.

It's coming up with a solid black fill.

Comment: Does the code run now?  To check add `msgbox("running")` in the code before the `If` statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40765/discussion-between-linger-and-user2887400)

Answer (score 0):

MS Access uses Conditional Formatting - much like MS Excel; I recommend this instead of using VBA to change the backcolor pragmatically.  This should work well for 'Continuous Forms.'