# Access: Randomly color ditinct data values

Tags: ms-access

In my Access report, how can I set about getting my text boxes colored depending on their values.  I can see that I can use conditional formating if I know my values in advance.  but how do I do it when I don't know how many different values there's going to be.
So, for example if my data produces A,D,C,C,D,B,A,A,B,  I'd like these colored in four different random colors.

Comment: this answre may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841554/access-vba-if-statement-to-change-back-and-font-color-of-a-report-field

Comment: Thanks but the question addressed there is for when you know what your values are going to be.  I don't know my values in advance.  I just want it so that each distinct value has its own colour.